# Can Astronauts Aboard ISS See the Shadow of The Moon on The Earth During an Eclipse?

Tags: solar-eclipse

I was wondering if the astronauts on the ISS are able to see the shadow from the moon on the earth at all during the eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here's an ISS photo [from the 2002 eclipse over the Indian ocean](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/eclipse-shadow-iss).
This year, 2017, the [ISS will see the moon's shadow on earth once](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/iss-observations), over southern Illinois, at 43.9% totality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did just a bit more googling and found [this article](http://earthsky.org/space/iss-astronauts-aug-21-2017-total-solar-eclipse) which does indeed show images of a shadow on the earth.  Pretty cool.